# Dataframe using unique but the rows is a list not a "1d array-like"

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = { 
    'Other':['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'], 
    'category':[['Transfer'], ['Unknown'], ['Transfer','Facebook'], ['Facebook', 'Google', 'Other'], ['C3']]
} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am trying to get a list of unique values for categories, unfortunately using

```
categories = df['category'].unique()
```

doesnt work, I am not sure what should be the approach to end with an outcome of

```
['Transfer', 'Unknown','Facebook','Google','Other','c3']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `explode`

```
df.category.explode().unique()
array(['Transfer', 'Unknown', 'Facebook', 'Google', 'Other', 'C3'],
      dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the unique list, you may use `pd.unique` on flatten of `df.category` using `np.concatenate`

```
l = pd.unique(np.concatenate(df.category))

Out[100]:
array(['Transfer', 'Unknown', 'Facebook', 'Google', 'Other', 'C3'],
      dtype=object)
```